# Rails 3 - routing, more parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am thinking about the solution of variable count parameters in URL.
In `routes.rb` I have following

> match ":a(/:b)" => "home#bla"

This mean I can have in URL **web.com/me**, **web.com/me/about-me** or **web.com/me/contact**. I would need to add to URL this: **web.com/me/one-thing/second-thing** => if will be in URL the second parameter **one-thing** (exactly this string), so then must be there the third parameter (and know on the position of third parameter could be whatever, but always something).

I tried to edit *routes.rb** with a following way:

> match ":a(/:b/:c)" => "home#something"
>   But this way is wrong...

Could anyone help me, please, how to edit my routes.rb for getting need effect?
Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
match ":a(/:b(/:c))" => "home#something"
```

Otherwise you could do

```
match ":a(/:b)" => "home#something"
match ":a(/:b/:c)" => "home#something"
```